# Network install OS and a few packages on 10 systems

Tags: ubuntu, installation, pxe-boot, netboot

This is something that I am currently working on.

I have 10 systems, that I would like to configure with lubuntu and virtual box.

Now, I know about network installation with PXE. I tried to do this with [Serva](http://www.vercot.com/~serva/) configured on another windows system. But the main problem with that is, I still need to go to every system and do all the installation. This only helped me in removing the need to carry the bootable drive to every system and install there.

Is there a solution which can provide me facility to install lubuntu remotely on all the systems simultaneously i.e. I only install it on one system and all the other desired systems would simply follow this.

I would also like to know if I can install virtual box remotely on all systems (Other than doing ssh to each system)

Thanks a lot in advance for every suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too wide to answer shortly, but the technology you are trying to find is called **preseeding**.

The process is similar in [Debian preseeding](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apb.html.en) and [Ubuntu preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-using.html).

With Lubuntu, automated deployments are supported in [Alternate install image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/)

Answer (score 0):

Serva allows you to PXE boot/install many OSs from a menu displayed at the booting client screen.
Serva's menu can be configured for automatically booting a predefined menu option.
Next you can use the automated features of the target OS for getting a full hands-off net install experience.

i.e. if you are installing Windows Vista and up you must create the file Unattended.xml.

If you are installing **Debian** you should use its **preseeding** capabilities.

If you are installing **Ubuntu** you can use its **preseeding** and/or **kickstart** capabilities

If you are installing **Red Hat** (and derivatives) you can use its **kickstart** capabilities.
etc

Answer (score 0):

Others pointed the right solution to preseeding, which is great solution for now, and I highly recommend to use it. But later you would need a solution to perform some task AFTER installation. Like adding new packages or users.

I would recommend you to read more about [Ansible](http://ansible.com) or [Chef](http://chef.io). They are extremely useful tools manage multiple configurations at once.